# enum type: is missing the following properties from type

Tags: typescript

I have some types defined as following:

```
export type Permission = keyof typeof UserPermissions | undefined;

export type Role = keyof typeof UserRoles;

export type PermissionMap = {
  [P in UserPermissions]: { [R in UserRoles]: boolean };
};
```

**UserPermissions** :

```
enum UserPermissions {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C',
  D = 'D',
  E = 'E',
}
```

**UserRoles**:

```
enum UserRoles {
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
  STANDARD = 'STANDARD',
}
```

When I define an object of type `PermissionMap` as following:

```
const permissions: PermissionMap = {
  [UserPermissions.A]: {
    [UserRoles.STANDARD]: false,
    [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
  },
  [UserPermissions.B]: {
    [UserRoles.STANDARD]: false,
    [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
  },
  [UserPermissions.C]: {
    [UserRoles.STANDARD]: true,
    [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
  },
};
```

I get the following error:

> Type '{ A: { STANDARD: false; ADMIN: true; }; B: { STANDARD: false;
> ADMIN: true; }; C: { STANDARD: true; ADMIN: true; }; }' is missing the
> following properties from type 'PermissionMap': D, E

And in another case:

```
const permissions: PermissionMap = {
      [UserPermissions.A]: {
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
      },
      [UserPermissions.B]: {
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
      },
      [UserPermissions.C]: {
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
      },
    };
```

I get the following error:

> Type of computed property's value is '{ ADMIN: true; }', which is not
> assignable to type '{ ADMIN: boolean; STANDARD: boolean; }'.
> Property 'STANDARD' is missing in type '{ ADMIN: true; }' but required
> in type '{ ADMIN: boolean; STANDARD: boolean; }'.ts(2418)

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THis type:

```js
export type PermissionMap = {
  [P in UserPermissions]: { [R in UserRoles]: boolean };
};
```

Means that there are required all `UserPermissions` keys: `A, B, C, D, E` whereas in `const permissions` you are using only `A, B, C`. If this is intentional, you can exclude `D, E` keys from `UserPermissions`.

So, you can parametrize `PermissionMap` type:

```js
enum UserPermissions {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C',
    D = 'D',
    E = 'E',
}

enum UserRoles {
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
    STANDARD = 'STANDARD',
}

export type Permission = keyof typeof UserPermissions | undefined;

export type Role = keyof typeof UserRoles;

export type PermissionMap<Without extends string = never> = {
    [P in Exclude<UserPermissions, Without>]: { [R in UserRoles]: boolean };
};

const permissions: PermissionMap<UserPermissions.D | UserPermissions.E> = {
    [UserPermissions.A]: {
        [UserRoles.STANDARD]: false,
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
    },
    [UserPermissions.B]: {
        [UserRoles.STANDARD]: false,
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
    },
    [UserPermissions.C]: {
        [UserRoles.STANDARD]: true,
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
    },
};
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBkEDm)

Or you can use [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type:

```js
enum UserPermissions {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C',
    D = 'D',
    E = 'E',
}

enum UserRoles {
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
    STANDARD = 'STANDARD',
}

export type Permission = keyof typeof UserPermissions | undefined;

export type Role = keyof typeof UserRoles;

export type PermissionMap = Partial<{
    [P in UserPermissions]: { [R in UserRoles]: boolean };
}>

const permissions: PermissionMap = {
    [UserPermissions.A]: {
        [UserRoles.STANDARD]: false,
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
    },
    [UserPermissions.B]: {
        [UserRoles.STANDARD]: false,
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
    },
    [UserPermissions.C]: {
        [UserRoles.STANDARD]: true,
        [UserRoles.ADMIN]: true,
    },
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2aYVW)